# NLog LogException seems to ignore the exception

Tags: logging, nlog, exception-logging

`LogException` or any of the derived functions like `ErrorException` etc. seem to totally ignore the exception parameter passed in.

Am I missing a format attribute in my `nlog.config` file?
I am using the boilerplate from the template that Nlog installs in VS.

I would expect information from the exception object AND inner exceptions to be added to the log file. Yet the only information added to the log file is the string parameter passed to the function.

Turns out that `ErrorException()` is actually less useful than `Error()`

How can I get more in depth reporting. Particularly a full recursive dump of the `Message` property of all inner `Exceptions`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Add or replace the `${exception}` tag in the layout config to `${exception:format=tostring}`

```xml
 <targets>
    <target name="errorLogFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="errors.txt" 
            layout="${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
</targets>
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this programatically?

Answer (score 32):

Building on @Niki's answer, this will give you pretty close to what log4net will do

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}${onexception:inner=${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}"
```