# Nlog Error(message, exception) ignore exception

Tags: exception, error-handling, .net-3.5, nlog

I have problem log exception only message is logged.

NLog config:

```
<target name="logfile"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="log.txt"
        layout="${longdate} | ${machinename} | ${processid} | ${processname} | ${level} | ${logger} | |${message} | ${exception:format=tostring}" />



<logger name="*"
        minlevel="Info"
        writeTo="logfile" />
```

**Usage:**

```
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    _logger.Error("my message", new Exception("my exception"));
```

**Log output:**

```
2014-04-24 18:17:29.0841 | PC_NAME | 6464 | APP_NAME.vshost | Error | AppName.ViewModel | my message |
```

Exception is ignore.

I found some [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566685/nlog-logexception-seems-to-ignore-the-exception) but for me not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nlog is using sepecial methods for logging exceptions which are using the `<loglevel>Exception` naming schema.

So in your case you need to use the `ErrorException` method in order to your exceptions get logged correctly:

```
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

_logger.ErrorException("my message", new Exception("my exception"));
```

Comment: NLog's ErrorException method has be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `void Error(string message, Exception exception);` is obsolete

You can use `ILogger.Error(Exception, string)` method like below

```
catch (Exception e)
{
 Log.Error(e, "it happens");
}
```

and a little bit modified layout with `${onexception}`. This will check is there an exception to be logged

```
<target name="logfile"
        xsi:type="File"
        fileName="log.txt"
        layout="${longdate} | ${machinename} | ${processid} | ${processname} | ${level} | ${logger} | |${message} ${onexception:| ${exception:format=tostring}}" />
```

/>